# Create parent object with child collection - "Framework 4.1 MVC 3.0"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1, edmx-designer

I would like to know how can I create parent object with its child collection in one step
using ADO.net Entity Data Model.

**Example:**
This is the parent object "Video" and its Child VideoData Diagram

[image: parent object "Video" and its Child VideoData]

I need to create video object with Video data

this is the razor view created by scaffolding options

```
@model Test.Models.Video

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Video</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddedDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddedDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddedDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsYouTube)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsYouTube)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsYouTube)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsApproved)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsApproved)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsApproved)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApprovedBy)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApprovedBy)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApprovedBy)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastModifiedDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastModifiedDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastModifiedDate)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

as you can notice, the razor view does not contain any fields associated with the related video data entity.

my question is: How can I add videoData to video creation process.

if it may help, here is the `HttpPost` Create in the `VideoController`

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Video video)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Videos.AddObject(video);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(video);
    }
```

I need the posted video object to contain its associated `VideoData collection`

Please advice

Comment: Where do the data for your `VideoData` objects come from and how many `VideoData` objects do you create each time a `Video` is created?